# Should access modifier of @findby be private or public?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using private access modifier for web elements located via `@FindBy`. e.g.

```
@FindBy(id="signin")
private WebElement loginButton;
```

and then I would expose this web element using getter and setter. 
However, I read somewhere that getter and setters are not required to be used with `@FindBy` as it internally has a private access modifier. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in Java you don't actually have getter and setter you'd better make all your elements private.

Then wrap them in methods which you'd call getters, setters or somehow else.

If you work with button it will never require a value so you don't need to have setter. In this case it's good idea to name your method like that: loginButton();
and use it as pageClass.loginButton().click();

But if you have a field and you want get values from it as well as set them then create two methods and call them getFieldValue(); and setFieldlValue();

Why is better to wrap your private field is because you'll be able to set restrictions in data to set to your fields and you'll be able to click to buttons safely (waiting for loading page and ajax right after clicking).

Answer (score 1):

> as it internally has a private access modifier. Is that correct?

That's not correct.

It depends on how you want access to your button.

Would you rather your user using

```
pageClass.loginButton.click()
```

or

```
pageClass.getLoginButton().click()
```

It's up to you on how you want that. `@FindBy` is just an annotation and it be instantiated with the same value regardless of its access modifier.

Comment: Understood. Please also let me know the better approach of the two,

    `pageClass.loginButton.click()`
or 
`pageClass.getLoginButton().click()`

keeping java best practices in mind.

Comment: i'd say the `pageClass.loginButton.click()`.  mainly because of the maintenance.  when an element is deleted from the page, you wouldn't need to worry about getters and setters.  a maintennence nightmare could arise if you use getters and setters.  `"hey, i have this webelement, why can't i use get*()?  oh.. because it doesn't have a getter"` :)